# Html Viewport size relative to Container and not to page

Tags: css, viewport-units

I've a component which is using vw and vh units. On its own, its working fine but now I want to embed this component into another page which contains some other stuff as well so this embedded component should adjust its width and height according to the parent element. How do I do it?

Comment: without any code showing your issue, hard to tell.  ...  you could take a look at the flexbox model. ...

Comment: @GCyrillus It is a general question that how can you adjust vh and vw according to their parent container and not to the page.

Comment: I think this is a good question, related questions existed shows the exact usage case. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container